# How to limit my laravel posts just on home page

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-blade

So I was wondering if I could limit the number of posts just for my homepage

**Homepage**

Here I check there are any posts and if so I display the latest one full width

```
    @if(count($posts) > 0)
        {{-- Get first post --}}
        <div class="col-sm-12" style="padding: 0px;">
            <a href="posts/{{$posts->first()->id}}">
                <div  class="post-icon">
                    <img style="width: 100%;" src="storage/cover_images/{{$posts->first()->cover_image }}">
                </div>
                <div class="bottom-left">
                    <button class="btn  bg-dark text-light" type="submit">
                        <h5>
                            {{$posts->first()->title}};
                        </h5>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="top-right-categorie">
                    <div class="categorie" style="background-color: {{$posts->first()->categorie['hex']}};">
                        {{$posts->first()->categorie['title']}}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="w-100">
            <br>
        </div>
    @endif
```

**PostController**

```
public function index()  
    {
        $posts = Post::all();
        return view('posts.index')->with('posts', $posts);
    }
```

**Page**
[image]

Comment: So you need only 3 posts for example?

Answer (score 0):

You can easily find this in the [Laravel's model documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent):

You can try:

```
$posts = Post::->take(2)->get();
return view('posts.index')->with('posts', $posts);
```

This will return the first 2 posts, replace "2" with the number of posts that you need

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
$post = Post::all()->limit(5);
return view('posts.index')->with('posts', $posts);
```

Or use pagination:

```
$post = Post::all()->paginate(5);
return view('posts.index')->with('posts', $posts);
```